# Using conditions inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this infinite scroll code which works perfectly fine.

I m trying to use if-else conditions inside my Code but due to some syntax (i think) error its not echoing out.

My code goes as :

```
function addrows(rows) {
        let postList = $("#post-list");
        $.each(rows, function (i, row) {
            var img = row.image;
            let rowHtml = `
                 <div class="mt-3">
             `+if (img == null){ +`
                    <a href="post?id=`+row.id+`" style="color:black;">
                       <p style="font-size: 30px;padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;">`+row.title+`</p>
                    </a>
             `+} else { +`
                    <a href="post">
                       <img src="images-main/images/`+row.image+`" alt="post-image" class="img-fluid rounded w-100">
                    </a>
              `+}+`
                 </div>
           `;
                        
            postList.append(rowHtml);            

        });
    }
```

Please note that the whole infinite scroll code works fine if I m to remove those if-else conditions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what errors do you get in the browser developer console?

Comment: @JaromandaX it says, unexpected token "if"

Comment: because `"str" + if (condtion) { + "true" + } else { + "false" + }` is nowhere near valid javascript ... use ternary operator ... `(condition) ? (value when true) : (value when false)` - for the above, I would use `()` liberally to make sure you get the right result

Comment: @JaromandaX i used this , and it says "unexpected var" `var beverage = (age >= 21) ? "Beer" : "Juice";
                            console.log(beverage);`

Comment: where did you put var? inside the `"string" + "another string"`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not concat the if else with the string, it is not valid syntax in javascript, either you can use the ternary conditional operator or using if else like this

```
  let postList = $("#post-list");
  $.each(rows, function (i, row) {
    var img = row.image;
    let rowHtml = `<div class="mt-3">`;
    if (img == null) {
      rowHtml += `<a href="post?id=` + row.id + `" style="color:black;">
                      <p style="font-size: 30px;padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;">`+ row.title + `</p>
                  </a>`;
    }
    else {
      rowHtml += `<a href = "post" >
                      <img src="images-main/images/`+ row.image + `" alt = "post-image" class="img-fluid rounded w-100" >
                  </a>`;
    }
    rowHtml += '< /div>';
    postList.append(rowHtml);
  });
}
```

Comment: and hei, can you help me with some other issue in the same code../

Comment: can you join this chat room, will explain the situation there. Thanks https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222945/discussion-between-wesley-smith-and-harry-k

Comment: Bro can you please respond on the chat

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, you cannot inline an `if..else` into string concatenation.

One thing jQuery makes very easy is DOM element creation and manipulation so why not use it

```js
function addrows(rows) {
  $("#post-list").append(rows.map(row => {
    const a = $("<a>")
    if (row.image) {
      a.append($("<img>", {
        src: `images-main/images/${row.image}`,
        alt: "post-image"
      }).addClass("img-fluid rounded w-100"))
    } else {
      a.css({ color: "black" }).append($("<p>", {
        text: row.title
      }).css({ fontSize: "30px", padding: "15px 30px" }))
    }
    
    return $("<div>").addClass("mt-3").append(a)
  })
}
```

Comment: Glad to know this as well. will practice on this